# how to auto populate the zeros in a textbox using a jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to auto populate the zeros in a textbox using a jquery or javascript? If I enter 6m in a textbox it should automatically consider the m as million and the text box needs to be populate as 6000000

- Input in TextBox : 6m
- Output needed : 6000000

This should happen while typing.

Comment: What if I enter `6000000m`? It will end up as `6000000000000`? And what about the input `6m6`? What it will be?

Comment: Similar to above - is `m` just replaced by 6 zeros?

Answer (score 0):

To replace an m with 6 zeros on enter you can do the following:

```js
$("#test").keyup(function() {
  var str = $(this).val();
  var rep = str.replace("m", "000000");
  $(this).val(rep)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" type="text"/>
```

The same with pure Javascript:

```js
document.getElementById("test").onkeyup = function() {
  var str = this.value;
  var rep = str.replace("m", "000000");
  this.value = rep;
}
```

```html
<input id="test" type="text"/>
```